# BULK INSERT Syntax SQL

Tags: c#, sql, bulkinsert

I can not get a SQL Bulk Insert Statement to Run via C# on my Web Server or locally.
I am trying to import data from a text file into a SQL Web Server.

After I connect to the Web server / SQL Server the 
The statement I am using is as as follows..

```
BULK INSERT dbo.FNSR
            FROM 'http:\\yahoodd.velocitytrading.net\txtfiles\FNSR.txt'
            WITH
            ( 
                FIRSTROW = '2',
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

then I get this error.

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\yahoodd.velocitytrading.net\txtfiles\FNSR.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 53(The network path was not found.).

I have tried this with 'http"://webserver.remotefile.txt' as listed above also... with a slightly different result (error code 123 dir, path not valid )

Any ideas??  I can not upload the txt file to the WebServer as a local txt file... what I am I doing wrong.. how is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

To specify a shared data file, use its universal naming convention (UNC) name, which takes the general form, \Servername\Sharename\Path\Filename. Additionally, the account used to access the data file must have the permissions that are required for reading the file on the remote disk.

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
   FROM '\\computer2\salesforce\dailyorders\neworders.txt';
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx

Comment: Its the issue of referencing an internet file that I am having issues with...remotely uploading a file from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Its two slashes and no http

```
BULK INSERT dbo.FNSR FROM '\\yahoodd.velocitytrading.net\txtfiles\FNSR.txt' 
WITH ( FIRSTROW = '2', FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )
```

Comment: It was due to the virtual path not being found I think... I am going to use an IP address but this does over come the initial error

Comment: I totally give up.. I have tried referencing IP address, moving it to parent domain, checking security profiles for having Bulk Insert Rights and it just will not see the file, I don't think this is possible, I am moving on to Bulk Copy using C# and DataTables

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a local drive.

The part *FROM 'http:\yahoodd.velocitytrading.net\txtfiles\FNSR.txt'* should be replaced by *C:.......\some.txt*.

If it's from *http://...* you will have to stream through it.