# Multithreading advice on approach needed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have been told to make a process that insert data for clients using multithreading.

Need to update a client database in a short period of time.There is an application that does the job but it's single threaded.Need to make it multithread.

The idea being is to insert data in batches using the existing application

EG
Process 50000 records
assign 5000 record to each thread

The idea is to fire 10-20 threads and even multiple instance of the same application to do the job.

Any ideas,suggestions examples how to approach this.
It's .net 2.0 unfortunately.

Are there any good example how to do it that you have come across,EG ThreadPool etc.

Reading on multithreading in the meantime

Comment: What kind of suggestions are you looking for here? With the lack of details, at most we can say is ... uhm, yeah, start multiple threads and divide the workload between them, just like you said.

Comment: Are all these inserts in the same table?

Comment: What's your outer problem? What do you expect to gain by having 10 threads over 1?

Comment: Absolutely hard to figure out how exactly it is possible to help you, I want really but your question is too absract, could you please be more specific and describe what kind of data, what kind of data structures are you using, what is Application's curet design now, ...

Comment: apology for lack of example.I have not gone into details as I have not being given all the details yet but I will tomorrow.It;s all inserts to same table ,which can can an issue with locking the table.tempted to delete this question and rewrite when I have more info

Comment: A thread can buy you more cpu cycles, it doesn't buy your more database servers.  Using 10 threads makes no sense.  Look into bulk updates for a possible speedup.

Comment: You can read about bulk insert here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415037/bulk-insert-syntax-sql but I have never used it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bet dollars to donuts the problem is that the existing code just uses an absurdly inefficient algorithm. Making it multi-threaded won't help unless you fix the algorithm too. And if you fix the algorithm, it likely will not need to be multi-threaded. This doesn't sound like the type of problem that typically benefits from multi-threading itself.

The only possible scenario I could see where this matters is if latency to the database is an issue. But if it's on the same LAN or in the same datacenter, that won't be an issue.